# Complex Matrix Derivative - Trace, high orders

Tags: matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

We have matrices $\mathbf{K} \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times M}$, $\mathbf{C} \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times M}$ for $N \leq M$ and a diagonal matrix $\mathbf{D} \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N}$.

Let function $f =
\text{tr}\{\mathbf{I}-2\mathbf{C}\mathbf{K}\mathbf{C}^{H}+\mathbf{C}\mathbf{K}\mathbf{C}^{H}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{K}\mathbf{C}^{H} -\mathbf{D}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{C}^H\}$.

Here, $(\cdot)^H$ is hermitian matrix operator.

Then, what is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{C}}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For convenience, define the variable 
$$A=KC^H$$
Then write the function in terms of this new variable and the [Frobenius (:) Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product) and find its differential
$$\eqalign{
 f &= I:I-2I:CA+I:CACA-I:DCC^H\cr
   &= I:I-2A^T:C+A^TC^T:CA-DC^*:C\cr\cr
df &= 0-2A^T:dC+A^TdC^T:CA+A^TC^T:dCA-DC^*:dC\cr
   &= -2A^T:dC+A^TC^TA^T:dC+A^TC^TA^T:dC-DC^*:dC\cr
   &= (2A^TC^TA^T-DC^*-2A^T):dC\cr
}$$
where $C^H=(C^T)^*$.

Since $df=\big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial C}:dC\big),\,$ the gradient must be
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial C} &= 2A^TC^TA^T-DC^*-2A^T \cr
  &= 2C^*K^TC^TC^*K^T-DC^*-2C^*K^T \cr\cr
}$$
Keep in mind that $\{C^*, C^H, A\}$ are independent of $C$ for [purposes of differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives).